# Change value in sql table from 0 to 1 when a reserve button is clicked

Tags: php

I am creating a very basic library system that will allow a user to login, register, search for a book and reserve that book. I have the login and register functions working, also the function to search the database is working.  My problem arises when i want to reserve the book. When i click the reserve button it works does not show any errors however my database will not update. 
If any of you can help me discover where the problem/problems lie i will be very grateful.

Also a side note i know my code is not very good and is open for injections i will approach injections once i have the apllication functioning correctly.

My code is below

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || (trim($_SESSION['username']) == ''))  {
header("location: login.php");
exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <style  type="text/css"> 
     ul  li{ 
     list-style-type:none; 
     } 
    </style> 
    <title>Search for and Reserve a Book</title>
</head>

<p><body>
<h3>Book Details</h3>
<p>You  may search either by Book Title, Author or Book Category</p>

<form  method="post" action="search_submit.php?go"  id="searchform">
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(isset($_GET['go']))
    {
        if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $_POST['name']))
        {

              $name=$_POST['name'];


              //connect  to the database
              $db=mysql_connect  ("localhost", "root",  "") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
              //-select  the database to use
              $mydb=mysql_select_db("bookreservations");
              //-query  the database table
              $sql="SELECT * FROM books WHERE  Author LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR BookTitle LIKE '%" . $name  ."%'";

              //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
                $result=mysql_query($sql);

                //-create  while loop and loop through result set
              while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
                      $ID = $row['id'];
                      $ISBN = $row['ISBN'];
                      $Author  =$row['Author'];
                      $BookTitle=$row['BookTitle'];
                      $CategoryId=$row['CategoryId'];

                        echo '<table cellpadding ="10" border = "2">';

                      echo '<th> ID </th>';
                      echo '<th> Author </th>';
                      echo '<th> Book Title </th>';
                      echo '<th> CategoryId </th>';
                      echo '<th> ISBN </th>';
                      echo '<th> Reserved </th>';
                      echo '<th> Reserve Book </th>';


                      echo'<tr>';
                      echo'<td>' .$ID.'</td>';
                      echo'<td>' .$BookTitle.'</td>';
                      echo'<td>' .$Author.'</td>';
                      echo'<td>' .$CategoryId.'</td>';
                      echo'<td>' .$ISBN.'</td>';
                      echo'<td>' .$Reserved.'</td>';
                      echo'<td><form method = "post" action="reserve.php">';
                      echo'<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Reserve">    </input>
            </td>';
            if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE books SET 'Reserved = 1' WHERE 'Reserved=0'";    
            }
            echo'</tr>';

            echo '</table>';     

                }

        }

        else
        {
             echo  "<p>Please enter a valid search query</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your sql is wrong: "UPDATE books SET 'Reserved = 1' WHERE 'Reserved=0' ". Use "UPDATE books SET Reserved = 1 WHERE Reserved=0". Remove those single quotes. This will set ALL books to reserved, is this really what you want?

Comment: No just the book the user has searched for. I'm not too sure on how to achieve this.

Comment: Hint: Don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated and will not be included in future php versions. Use mysqli_* functions/methods instead.

Comment: Or better yet, use PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

a) There is a mistake in your sql. Remove those single quotes around Reserved=X and use:

```
"UPDATE books SET Reserved = 1 WHERE Reserved=0"
```

Problem: This would reserve all of the books.

b) To make this statement only reserve 1 book you need to add the id of the book to be reserved to your reserve form:

```
echo'<td><form method = "post" action="reserve.php?book=' . $ID. '">';
echo'<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Reserve">
```

c) Use the $ID from b) to reserve only the book specified by $ID

```
"UPDATE books SET Reserved = 1 WHERE Reserved=0 and id = ". $_GET['book']
```

d) SQL injections are a serious problem within your code. Please double and triple check all sql statements. E.g. the statement from d) is affected. I will leave this as an exercise for you or simply ask another question about how to make your code secure.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will implement your suggestion, and I will definitely be looking into the SQL injections problem.

Comment: Hi maxhb i have tried your suggestion above but like before there is no change within my database. `code`     echo'<td><form method = "post" action="reserve.php?book=' . $ID. '">'; echo'<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Reserve"> </td>'; if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) { $mysqli->query = "UPDATE books SET Reserved = 1 WHERE Reserved = 0 and id = ". $_GET['book']; }

Comment: Please edit your question and add your complete new code.